# Magento Categories Out of Wack

Tags: magento-1.9, category-tree

I'm having an issue with Magento 1.9.2.0.  My categories on the left margin are lined up correctly, but not on the main page.  Take a look at this URL - http://tinyurl.com/huz6rnq and notice how the menu on the right is the preferred order, but on the main page its based on when I first set them up.  So all new items go to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had to add an extra line to the sub.phtml file.  That line of code was

->addAttributeToSort('position')

Credit goes to this article and read the comments for additional settings: 
https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento/magento-subcategories-category-pages